# How to generalize outer product into its integral form assuming continuous basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

(My current physics study is undergraduate quantum mechanics)

By definition, the inner product is $w^Tu= \sum_i w_iu_i$, the outer product is $wu^T=w_iu_j$. According to Griffith, the inner product integral is defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi(x)^*\Phi(x) dx$ and is equivalent to $\langle \Psi |\Phi\rangle $ in terms of wavefunctions. How would I apply such transformation so that the outer product $|\Psi\rangle\langle \Phi|$ can be written in integral form?

Something I have observed is that $\mathrm{tr}(wu^T) = w^Tu$. But I couldn't find a transformation from trace to an integral.

Comment: There is a wrong "continuous basis" wording being used. The basis is tipically discrete for the physical (bound) states. I would written "in terms of wavefunctions" instead of "under continuous basis" at the end of the second phrase from the second paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find the outer product of states in terms of wavefunctions by the usual approach of applying position kets to each state
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle \langle \Phi| \rightarrow \langle x|\Psi\rangle \langle \Phi| y \rangle = \Psi(x)\Phi^*(y)\;.
\end{equation}
No integrals required. We can go back the other way using the transformation
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x)\Phi^*(y) \rightarrow \int\mathrm{d}x\, | x\rangle\Psi(x)\int\mathrm{d}y\,\Phi^*(y) \langle y| = |\Psi\rangle \langle \Phi| 
\end{equation}
directly analogous to how it would be done for a simple wavefunction.

The trace identity you write down can be derived as
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}\left(|\Psi\rangle \langle \Phi|\right) &= \sum_i \langle \phi_i |\Psi\rangle \langle \Phi|\phi_i\rangle \\
&=  \sum_i \langle \Phi|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i |\Psi\rangle \\
&= \langle \Phi|\Psi\rangle\;.
\end{align}
Where $|\phi_i\rangle$ is some orthonormal basis (can be position or any other basis you like due to the basis independence of the trace.